# A partir de un gmail ya generado automática/. (script) desde lo cargado en un Formulario ¿Cómo puedo responder con una plantilla editable, ése correo?

Tags: google-apps-script

He conseguido que mis colegas (clientes internos) soliciten una evaluación X a sus requerimientos, completando un formulario de Google, datos los cuales quedan en una hoja de calculo y gracias a sus extensiones apps script y Html, automáticamente se envía un correo con aquella información, a ciertos destinatarios.

En una Planilla editable para las respuestas (hoja de calculo de Google) ¿cómo podría revisar mi bandeja de entrada y responder ése correo?

Comment: ¿No sería más práctico abrir una nueva pestaña y tener el correo electrónico ahí?

Comment: Hay varias formas de hacerlo pero seguramente la más práctica es ver tu correo directamente en el cliente de correo que uses habitualmente. Si de todas formas quieres hacerlo desde la hoja de cálculo deberás usar el servicio GmailApp. Si requieres mayor orientación, muestra lo que has intentado y agrega una breve descripción de tus esfuerzos por encontrar respuestas en este sitio útiles para esto.